# How to print Chinese characters in text file

Tags: java, html, chinese-locale

I am reading the data From text file and Printing in HTML file using java and Html code, But junk characters printing in HTML file

```java
report.reportGenerator("result.txt", reportHTMLFile, testCaseSheetMasterMap, environmentUrl, "01/01/01", "02/02/02");

StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // append html header and title
        //<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        htmlStringBuilder.append(
                "<html><head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>CitiGR Automation Report</title><style>p.padding { padding-top: 2cm;}</style></head>");
        // append body
        htmlStringBuilder.append("<body>");
        htmlStringBuilder.append("<p align=\"left\" style=\"color:red\"><h2><u>" + pageTitle + "</u></h2></p>");
        htmlStringBuilder.append("<p align=\"left\" class=\"padding\" style=\" text:red\"><b>Environment URL : <a href=\""+environmentUrl+"\">"+environmentUrl+"</a>");                                         
        htmlStringBuilder.append("<br><br>Start Run Time: "+startRunTime);                                         
        htmlStringBuilder.append("<br>End  Run Time &nbsp;: "+endRunTime+"</b></p>");               

        /* append 1st table */
        htmlStringBuilder.append(
                "<table border=\"1\" text-align:center><col width=\"50\"><col width=\"200\"><col width=\"200\"><col width=\"100\"><col width=\"100\"><col width=\"100\"><col width=\"100\">");
        // append row - table header
        htmlStringBuilder.append(
                "<tr>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"><b>Si.No.</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"><b>TestCase Name</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"><b>Total no. of scripts executed</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"green\"><b>Pass</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"red\"><b>Fail</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"green\"><b>Pass %</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"red\"><b>Fail %</b></td>"
                + "</tr>");

        int count=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < eachTestCaseMenuList.size(); ) {                        
            htmlStringBuilder.append(""
                    + "<tr>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\" >"+count+"</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\">"+ eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i) + "</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\">"+ eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i+1) + "</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\" style=\" color:DarkGreen\">" + eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i+2)+ "</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\" style=\" color:red\">" + eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i+3) + "</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\" style=\" color:DarkGreen\">" + eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i+4)+ "</td>"
                    + "<td align=\"center\" style=\" color:red\">" + eachTestCaseMenuList.get(i+5) + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>");
            i+=6;   
            count++;
        }       

        htmlStringBuilder.append(
                "<tr>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"><b>Total</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"LightBlue\"><b>"+totalTestCaseCount+"</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"green\"><b>"+totalPassCount+"</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"red\"><b>"+totalFailCount+"</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"green\"><b>"+totalPassPercent+" %</b></td>"
                + "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"red\"><b>"+totalFailPercent+" %</b></td>"
                + "</tr>");
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting ??? marks when I am printing chinese in HTML  , I used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> inside header line.

Comment: htmlStringBuilder.append((j + 1) + ") " + descriptionArray[j] + "<br>"); Appending array of Strings into to Strings Builder. Chinses Convertion is failing append to the string builder I am getting the ??? marks in HTML

Answer (score 1):

Short:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Long:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Still, I am facing the issue after adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

Include inside your `<head>` tags an encoding tag

Try as follows,

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will need to go in the < head > section of your web page.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

The server should be sending a response header like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If the "charset=UTF-8" bit is missing from the Content-Type response header, or if it says something other than "UTF-8", then this will cause you problems.